# При загрузке на сервер не отображаются иконочные шрифты

Tags: html, css, шрифты, иконки

При загрузке на сервер вместо иконок квадраты или другие символы. Шрифты Font-awesome и linea. При этом на локальной машине все отображается отлично.

```
libs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

в папке fonts лежат шрифты, но без версии.

Comment: Так путь импорта не верный судя по всему, если папка libs в корне укажите  `/libs....`

Comment: Тогда почему другие библиотеки работают исправно?
и еще на запрос файла fontawesome-webfont.woff статус 200 ОК, хотя он лежит в той же папке.

Comment: Покажите место импорта, для того чтобы разговаривать на одном языке.

Comment: http://antonivanov.website/portfolio/hostel/index.html в верхнем меню не отображается иконка вк и в разделе контакты не отображаются остальные иконки

Comment: Ну с css загрузка фонтов идет по пути `url(/libs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0);` а это конень всего сайта а не этого. добавьте путь от css файла т.е. думаю у вас это `url(../libs...`

Comment: `@font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    src: url(../libs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0);
    src: url(../libs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0) format('embedded-opentype'),......;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}`
Вроде так и прописан.  Когда сайт переносил на сервер я не менял его структуру и расположение файлов. т.е. просто добавил папку с готовым сайтом в папку портфолио. Остальные сайты в этой папке отображаются корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

хм так у вас импорт пятых, т.к. я поменял на `fab fa-vk` все показало. Не то на сервере.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частая ошибка вес иконок: `font-weight: 500;`
И получите: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, замена `fa` на `fab` помогло в верхнем меню. но в футере иконка все равно не отображается. и так же не отображаются иконки в контактах. я просто не могу понять почему в на локальном хосте все работает, а когда переносишь на сервер появляются ошибки.

Comment: Да я думаю у вам перебиваются шрифты. Добавьте иконке вес `font-weight: 500;`

Comment: Спасибо. Это помогло.